# JQuery Data value applying to all divs instead of just itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

I'll be honest, I'm VERY new to JQuery and still trying to muddle my way through it.  That being said I'm trying to create a simple parallax effect and I can't quite get it to work. Whenever I change the data-speed attribute it affects all the Divs of the same class instead of just the one it's on. So in the example below while the 2 divs should scroll at different speeds they scroll at the exact same speed (2) of whatever is in the first div.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="parallax" id="content1" data-speed="2">
Content
</div>
<div class="parallax" id="content2" data-speed="3">
Content 2
</div>
```

And my Jquery is:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

  // Enable parallax and fade effects on homepage sections
  $(window).scroll(function(speed){

    scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop()
    scrollwindow = scrolltop + $(window).height();
    speed = $(".parallax").data("speed")
    $(".parallax").css("backgroundPosition", "50% " + -(scrolltop*speed) + "px");

  });

});
```

I'm pretty sure this is just a case of me not being familiar with JQuery and how it works... Could somebody help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: In your function, you reference `.parallax1` and in the html, you have two `class="parallax"` ... change one to the other ...

Comment: Also, you might need to loop through the "parallax" classes and apply the CSS and speed individually: `.each()`

Answer (score 2):

Your issues are due to the following lines:

```
speed = $(".parallax").data("speed")
$(".parallax").css("backgroundPosition", "50% " + -(scrolltop*speed) + "px");
```

`$(".parallax")` selects *all* elements with `class="parallax"` but `.data("speed")` will only pull the value of the first element in the collection.

You're then applying that value to *all* `$(".parallax")` elements in the second line which explains the behavior you're seeing.

You instead need to loop through all your elements and apply `speed` individually:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(".parallax").each(function() {
        var $el = $(this),
            speed = $el.data("speed");

        $el.css("backgroundPosition", "50% " + -(scrolltop * speed) + "px");
    });
});
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking... Could you explain the fix?  I'm REALLY new to this and basically just stumbling my way through... Learning by doing/making mistakes sorta thing

Comment: You want to use jquery $.each and loop over each class/element.. Then inside of this loop access and apply the data... Or as the updated answer shows

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
// Enable parallax and fade effects on homepage sections
  $(window).scroll(function(speed){
    scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop()
    scrollwindow = scrolltop + $(window).height();
    var parallax = $(".parallax");
    $.each(parallax, function(index, value) {
      speed = $(parallax[index]).data("speed");
      $(parallax[index]).css("backgroundPosition", "50% " + -(scrolltop*speed) + "px");
  });
});
```

The loop should allow for the speed to be applied to each parallax class individually.